# Regex to match any strings containing Cyrillic symbols, except comments marked with //, ///, ///, etc

Tags: regex

I want to find all strings containing at least 1 Cyrillic character (basically /.*[А-я].*/) but with exception of comments.

Comment is a string or part of a string which starts with 2 or more / characters.
 Currently  I get this regex which do some part of the trick:

```
^(?=^.*?[А-я]+).*?((?=[\/]{2,})|(^(?:(?![\/]{2,}).)*$))
```

But I'd like to get less bloated and faster expression.

And as additional question: could anyone explain why this one is working? I combined it by trial-and-error but I'm not sure I completely understood how it works, because when I try to change it in any part - it stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will match any cyrllic character that is not preceded by a double forward slash

```
(?<!/{2}.*)[А-я]
```

It specifies that it should not be preceded by a double slash by using a negative lookbehind.

You haven't specified what flavour of regex your using, but be aware some flavours don't support lookarounds. For example PCRE (javascript) doesn't. You are using 3 of them in your regex, so i presume its ok.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Actually I forgot about minor detail so it should be `(?<!/{2}.*)[А-яЁё]` and it seems to work and much cleaner.